# SFTP connection getting reset by client server

Tags: sftp, windows-server, winscp

I am trying to to access one of my vendor SFTP using WinSCP from Windows Server. It was working fine but suddenly it's giving error while downloading uploading files. Error is

> Host is not communicating for more that 15 Seconds Still waiting.

and then it's giving

> Network error: Software caused connection abort.

Small files like 2kb 10 kb getting downloaded but large files not. When I am restarting the server it started working for some hours and then again same issue. Every time the server restarts it is working for some hours, but then same issue started.

1. tried to disable firewall on Windows Server – same issue
2. tried turning off optimization connection buffer size in WinSCP – same issue.
3. tried to disable antivirus – same issue.
4. tried to add route – it's started working for some hours then again – same issue
5. Restart the server working for some time and again – same issue
6. From same server I am able to connect with other vendors SFTPs and all size files are uploading/downloading is successful.
7. network side its showing source server is resetting the connection.
8. From an other server it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed by updating the MTU value. I have used below link for details related to how we can update MTU value.
https://iponwire.com/tcp-mss/